# Adding an animation controller to a UIImage in a canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to get an animated image in a canvas to animate, but I don't believe that sprite rendering works with canvas'. Ive tried adding an animation component to it however I need the image to have the controller on it, as it's animation changes all the time. How would I be able make the UIImage animated whilst still using the Animation controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an animation using Animation View and selected UIImage - Animation View will let you change UIImage sprites, position and more.
Then simply drop that animation into your Animation Controller and create whatever transitions you want.

Here you can read more about it:

[Animation View Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-UsingAnimationEditor.html)